# Memory leaking problem in iphone app

Tags: iphone, xcode, memory-leaks

i created one method like below one:

```
+ (JSONManager *)GetInstance
{
    if (!instance)
    {
        instance = [[JSONManager alloc] init];
    }
    return instance;
}
```

and i need to use same method in different view...if i release this one for the first view it is working fine and if trying to navigate to second view my app is crashing.

can any one please let me know where do i need to release that object

Thanks in advance

Comment: try releasing it in the other view where u are accessing this

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a singleton. You should not be releasing it in the first view. You will want to use the same instance throughout the lifetime of the application.

If that is not the requirement, you should provide the mechanism to set the `instance` variable to `nil` as it will be pointing to a deallocated object once you release it. But I think this is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks like a Singleton. The purpose of Singleton is to have a single instance of a resource available throughout an app.

So, you should not release the instance, after you are done with it in the first view, since you want to use it in another view.

If you are worried about releasing this instance have a look at the following link for a template singleton class for an iOS application:

http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/

Comment: ya this is the singleton...so there no way no release it but i am getting memory leak...what do i need to do to avoid leak

Comment: I have added a link for you to use as a template for singleton's in iOS apps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a true singleton use this template and generate it.
It's based on Apple's Singleton code
http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/objective-c-singleton-template-for-xcode-4/